# jquery - can't get text from span with 3 class names

Tags: jquery, text, html

I'm retrieving/fetching content with jQuery AJAX, displaying it on the page and trying to get text from the following span with 3 class names:

```
<span class="price eur priceData">198,91 €</span>
```

How can I get the number "198,91" from that span?

I'm using the following code to retrieve the text (which isn't working):

```
$("span.price.eur.priceData").text();
```

You've requested more code, here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                Read();
            });

            function Read() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "index.php?action=getData",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html == "BAD") {
                            $("#my_results").empty().append("Failed!");
                        } else {
                            $("#my_results").empty().append("Successful!");
                            $("#page_content").empty().append('<xmp>'+html+'</xmp>');
                            var text=$("span.price.eur.priceData").text();
                            alert(text);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

I've even tried to use SetTimeout() and Delay() and still didn't work.

Solution: (thanks to Shadow Wizard)

```
$(html).find("span.price.eur.priceData").text();
```

Comment: [JS Fiddle says you can](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g7xhA/). Any typos in your code (class-names in the `class` attribute, or in the jQuery selector)?

Comment: The code should work. Or at least it should get the number plus euro sign. Do you think you can create a reproducable case with jsFiddle?

Comment: This will get the text from span having **all three** classes - maybe you have only one or two?

Comment: @Gopesh I got nothing, not NULL, just nothing, alert message box was empty.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I tried with just one and two, and still didn't work. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @DavidThomas I've checked and rechecked the codes and can't find any typos.

Comment: @Gopesh I already answered that: " I got nothing, not NULL, just nothing, alert message box was empty."

Comment: @Erik try to alert 'html' and check what is getting there?

Comment: @Erik, can you provide some of the html as well?  Also, are you sure that `html != "BAD"` ?

Comment: @Erik - I've found the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails because you wrap the HTML contents with `<xmp>` tags, rendering them as pure text thus jQuery can't find any elements in there.

You can use the raw contents like this:

```
$("#my_results").empty().append("Successful!");
$("#page_content").empty().append('<xmp>'+html+'</xmp>');
var text = $(html).find("span.price.eur.priceData").text();
alert(text);
```

Comment: @Erik Cheers, if this solved the problem completely please mark this as accepted by ticking the empty V icon to the left. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a shot out of the dark since you haven't provided more code.

If you are retrieving the data via ajax, make sure your `$("span.price.eur.priceData").text();` is inside of your ajax success callback.

Otherwise, that `<span/>` element may not be populated with the data yet.

Comment: The only true answer here...! **+1**

Answer (score 1):

Hope that u need to get the actual value without the '€' symbol.
Check this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var text=$("span.price.eur.priceData").text();
   var text1=text.split('€')[0];
    alert(text1);

});
```

Check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z5AKU/

Answer (score 0):

Try with .html()

```
alert($("span.price.eur.priceData").html());​
```

Comment: Should not have any difference. (except encoding-decoding stuff)

Answer (score 0):

use any one class name....
I have used price .. so the code is as follow:

```
$('.price').html();

    **or**

    $('span.price').html();
```

Comment: Read the others comments in this page, You have **all** of their mistakes mixed...